# meaning of comma in bottom of binomial coefficient

Tags: probability, notation, binomial-coefficients

I know what the binomial coefficient means in combinatorics, e.g. $\binom6{2}$ means "6 choose 2" i.e. how many different subsets of size 2 can there be, out of a set of 6 elements.

But what does it mean when there is a comma in the bottom of the coefficient, for example $\binom6{2,2}$?

I saw this usage in the first answer here, and I'd never seen it before: [Problem 7, Ch1 from Blitzstein and Hwang, Intro to Probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1862026/problem-7-ch1-from-blitzstein-and-hwang-intro-to-probability)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2312648/what-does-a-binomial-coefficient-with-commas-mean  ??

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem

Comment: @iamwhoiam see my link above found it using google search.

Comment: Sorry guys, I am really tired and forgot to google. I will delete this.

Comment: Apparently I can't do that since it already has an answer. But feel free to do it yourselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as the multinomial coefficient:

$${k\choose t_1, t_2, ... , t_n }=\frac{k!}{t_1! \ldots t_n!}$$

As mentioned in the comments, we must have that $t_1+t_2+\dots +t_n = k$

Comment: It should be specified that this notation requires $t_1+t_2+\dots+t_n=k$.  The notation $\binom{6}{2,2}$ is meaningless as far as I'm aware since $2+2\neq 6$.  Also, it isn't the multinomial **theorem**, it is merely a multinomial coefficient.

Comment: This is true. I will add to the answer

Comment: If $\binom6{2,2}$ is meaningless, then that would imply the accepted answer at the question I linked is wrong. But it seems more like they mean something like "choose 2 from 6, then choose 2 again [from the remaining 4]", at least reading between the lines of the answer...

Comment: If you want to be pedantic, we can say $\binom{6}{2,2}$ is equal to zero since there are no ways to partition a set of $6$ elements into an ordered partition of partsizes $2$ and $2$.